# iOS 11.3 & iTunes 12.7.3 - any way out?

Tags: ios, itunes

I've been resisting moving to iTunes 12.7 as Apple have removed functionality & are insisting on far greater reliance on OTA than I am happy with.

iTunes 12.6.3 was touted as the 'opt out' version which kept Apps locally yet was capable of handling iOS 11.

As of iOS 11.3 this appears to no longer be the case & it is insisting on updating to iTunes 12.7.3 [even though I'm aware 12.7.4 is out] in order to update the iOS.

Is there any way round this; or does 12.7.3/4 restore any of the old functionality?
I remember the trouble I had originally reverting to 12.6 after falling for the 12.7 'upgrade' last year & don't want to have to repeat that if I can avoid it.

< rant> *I really am becoming quite disenchanted with Apple & their insistence on dumbing down each successive version of both Apps & OS* < /rant>

I suppose I'd also be happy with "Use 12.7.4, it really is better because..."

Comment: I can totally relate. I've stuck with iTunes 12.6.3 on my macOS Sierra (and earlier) Macs, but on the iMac Pro (which shipped with macOS High Sierra) I just use Apple Configurator 2 now for backups, installing apps, etc with my iOS devices, and use iTunes for any music etc related syncs. Maybe something worth considering. As for iTunes generally, it's really grown into quite a piece of bloated software over the past 5 - 10 years, so maybe iTunes 12.7 was partly a recognition of that by Apple, although it really does still try to do too much IMHO.

Comment: This thread (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8337987) from the Apple Discussion Boards suggests that (after backupping!) one may update to iTunes 12.7, update to iOS 11.3, then backtrack and reinstall iTunes 12.6.3, which provides App Store access and does synch with iOS 11.3.

Comment: Ahh, that sounds promising. I'll investigate tomorrow - I already cloned my boot drive just in case ;-)

Comment: @Monomeeth - User reviews on Apple Configurator 2 are rather off-putting; might give that one a miss :/

Answer (score 1):

I may have found a workaround, rather than a solution...

I kept iTunes 12.6.3 & did the iOS 11.3 update OTA.
iTunes can still sync/backup & still keeps the older apps features operable.

I imagine this workaround will fail the first time I need to set up a new iDevice or restore from a backup.

Comment: How'd you do that? My iTunes (12.6.3) says iOS 11.3 is available. When I click the "download" button, a dialog says iTunes 12.7 is required, and I can choose "cancel" or "download." "Cancel" backs me out of the process; "download" takes me to the App Store, where nothing happens and nothing is downloaded. On the iPhone, Settings > General > Software Update shows 11.3 as available, but there's no "download and install" link.

Comment: My workaround: download iTunes 12.7 from Apple, install it on the Mac. Then retrieve the iTunes 12.6.4 .dmg file from my computer's storage, and install 12.6.4 on top of 12.7. On launch, however, 12.6.4 says it can't read the iTunes Library .itl file, apparently a product of the installation of 12.7. I then retrieved my iTunes Library.itl file from a backup of this morning, and replaced the 12.7-created .itl file. Update iOS to 11.3. Finally, then, iTunes 12.6.4 launched correctly, showed my content and access to the App Store, and permitted synching. What a PITA.